# Pregel API - why iterations on small graph are consuming so much memory?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-graphx

I'm relatively new to Spark and Scala however I've decided to post here an example of code that is quite simple and in my perception shouldn't cause a serious problem, however in practice it cause Out of Memory error quite often in AWS EMR Spark environment depending on the value of `maxIterations` :

```
import java.net.URI

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, FileUtil, Path}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.graphx._

import scala.util.Try
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils
import java.io.IOException

val config = new SparkConf().setAppName("test graphx")
config.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")
val batch_id=new Integer(31)

val maxIterations=2 //200 interations are causing out of memory

var myVertices = sc.makeRDD(Array( (1L,  ("A",batch_id,0.0,0.0,0.0,11.0)), (2L,  ("B",batch_id,0.0,1000.0,0.0,300.0)), (3L, ( "C", batch_id, 1000.0, 1000.0, 0.0, 8.0)), (4L,  ("D",batch_id,1000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 400.0)) ))
var myEdges = sc.makeRDD(Array(Edge(4L, 3L, (7.7, 0.0) ), Edge(2L, 3L, (5.0, 0.0) ), Edge(2L, 1L, (12.0, 0.0))))

var myGraph=Graph(myVertices,myEdges)
    myGraph.cache
    
myGraph.triplets.foreach(println)

//we need to calculate some constant values for each edge before start of pregel
val initGraph=myGraph.mapTriplets(tr => 
    (tr.attr._1,  (tr.attr._1 * 
                    (scala.math.sqrt((tr.dstAttr._3-tr.srcAttr._3)*(tr.dstAttr._3-tr.srcAttr._3)+( tr.dstAttr._4-tr.srcAttr._4)*( tr.dstAttr._4-tr.srcAttr._4)+(tr.dstAttr._5-tr.srcAttr._5)*(tr.dstAttr._5-tr.srcAttr._5))) *
                    (scala.math.sqrt((tr.dstAttr._3-tr.srcAttr._3)*(tr.dstAttr._3-tr.srcAttr._3)+( tr.dstAttr._4-tr.srcAttr._4)*( tr.dstAttr._4-tr.srcAttr._4)+(tr.dstAttr._5-tr.srcAttr._5)*(tr.dstAttr._5-tr.srcAttr._5))) /
                    (tr.dstAttr._6 * tr.dstAttr._6)) 
    )
    
)

initGraph.triplets.take(100).foreach(println)

val distanceStep = 0.1
val tolerance = 1


val sssp = initGraph.pregel( (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), maxIterations //500-3000
 )(
  (id: VertexId, vert: ((String, Integer, Double, Double, Double, Double)), msg: (Double, Double, Double, Double)) =>
    (
      vert._1,vert._2,
      ( if (scala.math.abs(msg._1)> tolerance) {vert._3+distanceStep*msg._1 } else { vert._3 }),
      ( if (scala.math.abs(msg._2)> tolerance) {vert._4+distanceStep*msg._2 } else { vert._4 }),
      ( if (scala.math.abs(msg._3)> tolerance) {vert._5+distanceStep*msg._3 } else { vert._5 }),
      vert._6
    ),// Vertex Program
  e => {  // Send Message
    Iterator(
      (
        e.dstId,
        (
          ((e.srcAttr._3 - e.dstAttr._3)*distanceStep*scala.math.sqrt( 2*e.attr._2*e.srcAttr._6 / ((e.dstAttr._3-e.srcAttr._3)*(e.dstAttr._3-e.srcAttr._3)+( e.dstAttr._4-e.srcAttr._4)*( e.dstAttr._4-e.srcAttr._4)+(e.dstAttr._5-e.srcAttr._5)*(e.dstAttr._5-e.srcAttr._5)) )), //x
          ((e.srcAttr._4 - e.dstAttr._4)*distanceStep*scala.math.sqrt( 2*e.attr._2*e.srcAttr._6 / ((e.dstAttr._3-e.srcAttr._3)*(e.dstAttr._3-e.srcAttr._3)+( e.dstAttr._4-e.srcAttr._4)*( e.dstAttr._4-e.srcAttr._4)+(e.dstAttr._5-e.srcAttr._5)*(e.dstAttr._5-e.srcAttr._5)) )), //y
          ((e.srcAttr._5 - e.dstAttr._5)*distanceStep*scala.math.sqrt( 2*e.attr._2*e.srcAttr._6 / ((e.dstAttr._3-e.srcAttr._3)*(e.dstAttr._3-e.srcAttr._3)+( e.dstAttr._4-e.srcAttr._4)*( e.dstAttr._4-e.srcAttr._4)+(e.dstAttr._5-e.srcAttr._5)*(e.dstAttr._5-e.srcAttr._5)) )), //z
          e.attr._1*distanceStep*scala.math.sqrt((e.dstAttr._3-e.srcAttr._3)*(e.dstAttr._3-e.srcAttr._3)+( e.dstAttr._4-e.srcAttr._4)*( e.dstAttr._4-e.srcAttr._4)+(e.dstAttr._5-e.srcAttr._5)*(e.dstAttr._5-e.srcAttr._5)) //vector module
        )
      )
    )
  },
  {
    (a, b) => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2, a._3 + b._3, 0) // Merge Message
  }
)

sssp.vertices.take(10).foreach(println)
```

I run it in AWS EMR on 4 node m5.x2large cluster via Zeppelin, however it can be quickly adopted and executed as a job in spark.

In short this code creates a `myGraph` graph with 4 vertices and 3 edges. then for each triplet I calculate some constants value and use graph object `initGraph` for this.

Then for `initGraph` I apply pregel API which execution is only limited by number of iterations `maxIterations`. And at this moment for Pregel API I see strange behavior. For small `maxIterations` values (less than 10) it works quite fast, for 100-150 iterations it is performing for 3-4minutes in zeppelin, and for 200 iterations it fails with different errors (ConnectionClosed etc).

I tried to monitor what's going on with the cluster once I put maxIterations= 150 or 200 and it looks like this [image] Allocated memory goes straight up and available memory is decreasing at the same pace.

As I'm quite new to Spark I'm not sure this is correct behavior and quite honestly, I can't find an explanation of what could consume gigabytes of memory even with 200 iterations of pregel on such a small graph. If you can reproduce it on your end and check, I'm curios to listen to your advice on performance optimization, because if I expand the cluster and run the same code on a larger hardware setup, it simply just a question of `maxIterations` and size of graph to actually get same OutOfMemory error. And real graph I need to run this on is more than 1M vertices and ~7M edges so I can't figure out what kind of hardware it might require if this problem won't be solved.